# Is this a valid proof that the sequence $x_{n+1} = \sqrt{6+x_n}$ with $x_1 = 10$ is monotonically decreasing?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, solution-verification

Let $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a real sequence defined by $x_{n+1} = \sqrt{6 + x_n}$ and $x_1 = 10$.

We aim to show that $x_{n+1} < x_n$, that is $\sqrt{6 + x_n} < \sqrt{6 + x_{n-1}}$. Cancelling tells us that $x_n < x_{n-1}$. So overall we have $$x_{n+1} < x_n \iff x_n < x_{n-1} .$$

Since $x_2 = 4$ < $x_1 = 10$, we must have $x_{n+1} < x_n$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, hence $x_n$ is a monotonically decreasing sequence.

---

I think this is correct, but I feel like I might be wrong about the equivalence between $x_{n+1} < x_n$ and $x_n < x_{n-1}$.

Comment: @user376343 Why would this not be valid? Even if it were not valid, it would not hurt to elaborate a little, as just saying "it's not valid" doesn't really help OP...

Comment: It's okay. Fundamentally, this is because $\sqrt {x+6}$ is an increasing function where defined, so if $-6\leq a<b$ then $\sqrt{a+6}<\sqrt{b+6}.$ Then, as you note, you just need the case $x_2<x_1.$

Comment: While the statements are correct, the way you word your demonstration - particularly the "cancelling" statement - *sounds like* your deduction is based on bad algebra. A better demonstration would be $$\begin{align}0 < x_n < x_{n-1} &\iff 0 < 6 + x_n < 6 + x_{n-1}\\&\iff 0 < \sqrt{6 + x_n} < \sqrt{6 + x_{n-1}}\\&\iff 0 < x_{n+1} < x_n\end{align}$$

Comment: Perhaps a good way to express my point is: If you yourself are not fully convinced by your own argument, then you *really* need to put more details into your proof. Don't cut corners out of laziness.